# GAE and Objectify. is it possible to mark a field so that it won't get persisted?

Tags: google-app-engine, annotations, objectify

is it possible to mark a field in a class so that objectify (3.1)  will not persist it?

I've been reading up on @Transient and @NotSaved.  What is the difference?

Thanks!
Jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@NotSaved` fields will be loaded from the datastore, but they won't be saved. `@Transient` fields are completely ignored.

See this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/qizKUod_lUc

Comment: What about @Ignore?  Is that just for Ofy 4?

Comment: Yes, @Ignore is Objectify 4. See _Annotation changes_ at https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/DesignObjectify4

Comment: You should write this explanation on Objectify Wiki Page. It is much more understandable.